# How to Update Table with Using Inner Join and Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem :

Table1

```
CatId - -   Type - -    Qty
==============================
8        ||    O   ||   10
8        ||    N   ||   20
8        ||    U   ||   30
30       ||    N   ||   5
30       ||    O   ||   15
30       || NULL   ||   25
```

---

Table2

```
catId -- Old -    -New -- Useless -- Other
========================================
8      || 100   || 70   ||  140      || 110
30     || 10    || 20   ||  30       || 50
```

---

Result: Update Table 2  with Table 1 Like

```
-------------------------------------------------
catId --   Old --   New -- Useless -- Other
8       || 90    || 50  ||  110     || 110
30      ||  5    ||  5  ||  30      || 25
```

How result should come :

Table 1 and Table 2 has a common column CatId.

```
Column of table 1 Type is connects with Table2  
    AS  (Old - O / New - N / Useless - U / Other - NULL)
```

I want subtract Like table2(Respective  O/N/U/Other)  = table2(Respective O/N/U/Other) - table1(Type) and would prefer solution without loop

I tried this but not working Properly --

```
Update Table2
Set New = New - (CASE Type WHEN 'N' THEN (Table1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Old = Old  - (CASE Type WHEN 'O' THEN (Table1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Old = Old  - (CASE Type WHEN 'O' THEN (Table1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Other= Othere- (CASE Type WHEN is Null THEN (Table1.qty) Else 0 End)
from table1 
inner join table2 
On table1.catId = table2 .catId
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Update t2
Set New = New - (CASE WHEN type='N' THEN (t1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Old = Old  - (CASE WHEN type='O' THEN (t1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Useless = Useless  - (CASE WHEN type='U' THEN (t1.qty) Else 0 End),
    Other= Other - (CASE WHEN type is Null THEN (t1.qty) Else 0 End)
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
On t1.catId = t2.catId
```

What was wrong:

- in an `Update` with joins, specify the update table using an alias (`t2` in our case). Please see the documentation of the [TSQL Update statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)
- the `Old = Old - [...]` row was duplicated - I put the `Useless = [...]` row instead
- the `CASE` syntax was wrong: (`CASE <var> WHEN <value> [...]` is wrong; `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <value> [...]` is correct) please see the documentation of [the TSQL CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way. I first used a `PIVOT` to alter the set up of Table1 and then performed the JOIN to table2.  This is giving you the results that you wanted. This will show you a `SELECT` of the data that you want

```
create table #t1
(
    catid int,
    type varchar(5),
    qty int
)
create table #t2
(
    catid int,
    old int,
    new int,
    useless int,
    other int
)

insert into #t1 values(8, 'O', 10)
insert into #t1 values(8, 'N', 20)
insert into #t1 values(8, 'U', 30)
insert into #t1 values(30, 'N', 5)
insert into #t1 values(30, 'O', 15)
insert into #t1 values(30, null, 25)

insert into #t2 values(8, 100, 70, 140, 110)
insert into #t2 values(30, 10, 20, 30, 50)

select t2.catid 
    , t2.Old - t1.old as Old
    , t2.new - t1.new as New
    , t2.Useless - t1.useless as Useless
    , t2.other - t1.other as Other
from #t2 t2
INNER JOIN 
(
    select catid
        , IsNull([O], 0) as Old
        , IsNull([N], 0) as New
        , IsNull([U], 0) as useless
        , IsNull([null], 0) as other
    from
    (
        select catid, type, qty
        from #t1
    ) x
    PIVOT
    (
        max(qty)
        for type in([O], [N], [U], [null])
    ) p
) t1
    on t2.catid = t1.catid
```

Results:

```
catid   Old   New   Useless   Other
8       90    50    110       110
30      -5    15    30        50
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c004/1) with a demo of it working.

Then if you want to `UPDATE` table2 you would do the following:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Old = t2.Old - t1.old
    , t2.new  = t2.new - t1.new
    , t2.Useless = t2.Useless - t1.useless
    , t2.other = t2.other - t1.other
from #t2 t2
INNER JOIN 
(
    select catid
        , IsNull([O], 0) as Old
        , IsNull([N], 0) as New
        , IsNull([U], 0) as useless
        , IsNull([null], 0) as other
    from
    (
        select catid, type, qty
        from #t1
    ) x
    PIVOT
    (
        max(qty)
        for type in([O], [N], [U], [null])
    ) p
) t1
    on t2.catid = t1.catid
```